# Difference between $R^\infty$ and $R^\omega$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, notation

I know $R^\omega$ is the set of functions from $\omega$ to $R$. I would think $R^\infty$ as the limit of $R^n$, but isn't that $R^\omega$?
The seem to be used differently, but I can't tell exactly how.

Comment: Notations mean what their users want. Without context, it is impossible to decide what either of these notatins you mention mean. (Limit in what sense?)

Comment: This will manifest itself in people answering completely different things, due to their familiarity with different conventions. It does not helpthat each answer appears to think that their answer is authoritative :-(

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616815/what-are-default-topologies-on-r%e2%88%9e-and-r%cf%89

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a context where one makes a distiction between $R^\infty$ and $R^\omega$, 
$R^\infty$ denotes the set of sequences with finite support whereas $R^\omega$ denotes the set of unrestricted sequences.

In this context, $R^\infty$ is the limit of $R^n$ when $n \to \infty$, in the sense that $R^\infty = \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} R^n$, with the convention that $R^n$ are all seen as subsets of $R^\omega$.

Comment: To extend the original question: What are default topologies on $R^∞$ and $R^ω$? I would think that we take product topology on $R^ω$ and limit topology on $R^∞$ (in the sense of direct limit in category of topological spaces, if I remeber in this case it corresponds to subspace topology of box product).