# What are default topologies on $R^∞$ and $R^ω$?

Tags: general-topology, notation

To extend the original question [Difference between $R^\infty$ and $R^\omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616651/difference-between-r-infty-and-r-omega):  What are default topologies on $R^∞$ and $R^ω$?

I would think that we take product topology on $R^ω$ and limit topology on $R^∞$ (in the sense of direct limit in category of topological spaces, if I remeber in this case it corresponds to subspace topology of box product).