# What is $\mathbb R^\omega$?

Tags: general-topology, notation

I have seen  $\mathbb R^\omega$ mentioned in my topology texts but cannot find where $\omega$ is defined. Could someone please tell me what it means in comparison to $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: $\omega$ is the smallest infinite ordinal. When you're not considering the ordinal aspects, $\mathbb{N}$ is a commonly used name. $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is the space of all real sequences, the product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616651/difference-between-r-infty-and-r-omega.

Answer (score 4):

**tl; dr;**

$$X^\omega = X\times X\times\cdots$$

is an infinite countable product of $X$, i.e. the set of all countable sequences over $X$.

**Longer explanation:** so $\omega$ is [an ordinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) defined as the ordinal number of naturals $\mathbb{N}$. If we use [the Von Neumann definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) of ordinals then for an ordinal number $k$ we have a very straight forward generalization of finite Cartesian product:

$$X^k=\{f:k\to X\ |\ f\text{ is a function}\}$$

and so you can think about $X^k$ as the set of all **ordered** "sequences" with values in $X$. For finite $n$ this coincides with classical finite product because $n$ as a Von Neumann ordinal is recursively defined as $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ with $0=\emptyset$. For $\omega$ (which in Von Neumann case is simply $\mathbb{N}$) this coincides with the usual notion of sequences. For uncountable ordinals this probably goes beyond any intuition. Nevertheless typically by $X^\omega$ people understand the countable infinite product $X\times X\times\cdots$.

Note that there are alternative (and arguably simplier) definitions of an infinite Cartesian product, e.g. the set of all choice functions.

Answer (score -2):

The cardinality of $\Bbb N$, which is usually written $\aleph_0$ (the smallest infinite cardinal), is sometimes/often also written $\omega$. In other words

$$|\Bbb N| = \aleph_0 = \omega$$

Hence $\Bbb R^{\omega} = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \dots$ is the cartesian product of countably infinitely many $\Bbb R$.

Comment: $\omega$ **is not** a cardinal number. It's an ordinal number. And $\aleph_0=\omega$ is simply wrong.

Comment: That is not true

Comment: @freakish In set theory, cardinal numbers are often identified with corresponding initial ordinals. This is not "simply wrong", but at best it's misleading

Comment: @Wojowu These are apples and oranges. Perhaps there are people who identify them (how?) but they are simply wrong. It's like saying that there are people identifying groups with their underlying sets. No, this is wrong. Ordinals have much richer structure.

Comment: @freakish Let me say more - some people _define_ cardinal numbers as initial ordinals - for instance [Halmos](http://prntscr.com/m25jfs) or [Jech](http://prntscr.com/m25jno). This is different from what is done with groups and underlying sets.

Comment: @Wojowu well I find this approach extremely abusive. And it requires the Axiom of Choice to coincide with the classical definition.

Comment: @freakish - I'm curious what definition of cardinal number you're used to; defining cardinals as initial ordinals is 100% standard in the literature.