# How to denote a function with finitely many functions as arguments?

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose one has a function $f : X \times U \to X$. Then the space of all such functions is $X^{X\times U}$.

Suppose one wants to create a function $F$ that takes a finite sequence of such a functions as its arguments and produces a unique function of the same kind. If it is assumed that the sequence of arguments is a 2-tuple, then $F$ would be binary and denoted as
$$
F : \left(X^{X\times U}\right)^2 \to X^{X\times U}.
$$

But, what if the sequence of arguments to $F$ is arbitrarily finite, how is that denoted?

Comment: $2 \times Z$ is the disjoint union of two copies of $Z$, which is not the same as 2-tuples of elements of $Z$. The set of $n$-tuples of elements of $Z$ can be written as the set of functions $\{1, \ldots, n\} \to Z$ (or $Z^{\{1, \ldots, n\}} $).

Comment: @DonThousand: surely $Z^\omega$ is the set of infinite sequences of elements of $Z$ (which isn't what the OP wants).

Comment: The OP is using $A^B$ to mean the set of **all** functions from $B$ to $A$ according to the first line of the question.

Comment: To clarify $F$ should work like this: $f_{unique} = F(f_0, f_1, \dots f_n)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @DonThousand : I thought $$Z^{\omega} = \prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}Z$$ isn't it?

Comment: @MPW In the books I've seen, $$Z^\omega=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty Z^n$$$$Z^{\mathbb N}=\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty Z$$

Comment: @DonThousand : See [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756438/what-is-mathbb-r-omega). But in your defense, I would guess there are several different definitions of this symbol.

Comment: @RobArthan Under that definition, I agree that my notation is incorrect.

Comment: @DonThousand : I just checked Munkres and his definition is what I mentioned: The set $X^{\omega}$ is the collection of all tuples $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, i.e., it is the countable product of copies of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that $F$ takes an argument which is a finite sequence in $X^{X\times U}$ of any positive length, and $F$ returns values in $X^{X\times U}$, then it seems this would be a map

$$F:\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (X^{X\times U})^n\to X^{X\times U}$$

Or perhaps more clearly,

$$F:\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathscr{F}^n\to \mathscr{F}$$
where $\mathscr{F} = X^{X\times U}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a generalised Cartesian product?

Comment: @cisprague : Hmm, I don't think so. Any argument of $F$ is either in $\mathscr F$, or in $\mathscr{F\times F}$, or in $\mathscr{F\times F\times F}$, etc. so a typical element is of the form $(f_1)$ or $(f_1,f_2)$ or $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ etc which is what OP specified. If you mean that the domain should be $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathscr{F}^n$, then that would mean the typical element would be of the form $((f_{11}),(f_{21},f_{22}),(f_{31},f_{32},f_{33}),\cdots)$, which is an infinite sequence of finite sequences, right?

Comment: Given $f_0 = F(f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n)$ is there something else I could show to say that $f_0$ is different from the arguments to $F$? Maybe $\forall i \in \mathbb{N} : f_0 \neq f_i$?